# Sql to order results by sum

Tags: sql, oracle

DB used - Oracle

```
create table customer_exercise(
customer_id number,
exercise_id number,
cnt number,
exercise_date date)
```

Table data

```
1000    10  3   17-DEC-15
1001    20  6   19-DEC-15
1000    20  2   20-DEC-15
1003    20  9   20-DEC-15
1000    20  6   22-DEC-15
1000    30  10  23-DEC-15
1001    10  25  10-DEC-15
```

Is it possible to get results using sql such that sum(cnt) for exercise_id 20 appears first in the resultset?

```
select customer_id , exercise_id, sum(cnt) from customer_exercise 
where customer_id in (1000, 1001, 1003) and exercise_id in (20)
group by customer_id, exercise_id order by sum(cnt)

1001    20  6
1000    20  8
1003    20  9


select customer_id , exercise_id, sum(cnt) from customer_exercise 
where customer_id in (1000, 1001, 1003) and exercise_id not in (20)
group by customer_id, exercise_id order by sum(cnt)

1000    10  3
1000    30  10
1001    10  25
```

What I am trying to do is merge the results of above two queries with one sql. Is it possible to write a single sql that will fetch the resultset like below?

```
1001    20  6
1000    20  8
1003    20  9
1000    10  3
1000    30  10
1001    10  25
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that would be:

```
select customer_id , exercise_id, sum(cnt)
from customer_exercise 
where customer_id in (1000, 1001, 1003) 
group by customer_id, exercise_id
order by (case when exercise_id in (20) then 1 else 2 end), sum(cnt)
```